# MorningStar KeyStat to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read keyStat in MorningStar and know the data which is HTML where is warped in a JSON. So far I can put a request that can get the json by Beautifulsoup:

```
url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/keystatsAjax.html?t=tou&culture=en-CA&region=CAN'
lm_json = requests.get(url).json()
ksContent = BeautifulSoup(lm_json["ksContent"],"html.parser")
```

Now here is a bit wired to me that the html data as 'ksContent' which contains actual data as a table. I am not a fan of html and wondering how can I just make all it to a nice pandas dataframe? As the table is long, here is some of it:

```
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="r_table1 text2">
     <colgroup>
        <col width="23%"/>
        <col span="11" width="7%"/>
     </colgroup>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th align="left" scope="row"></th>
           <th align="right" id="Y0" scope="col">2008-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y1" scope="col">2009-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y2" scope="col">2010-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y3" scope="col">2011-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y4" scope="col">2012-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y5" scope="col">2013-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y6" scope="col">2014-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y7" scope="col">2015-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y8" scope="col">2016-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y9" scope="col">2017-12</th>
           <th align="right" id="Y10" scope="col">TTM</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr class="hr">
           <td colspan="12"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th class="row_lbl" id="i0" scope="row">Revenue <span>CAD Mil</span></th>
           <td align="right" headers="Y0 i0">—</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y1 i0">40</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y2 i0">212</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y3 i0">349</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y4 i0">442</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y5 i0">759</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y6 i0">1,379</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y7 i0">1,074</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y8 i0">1,125</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y9 i0">1,662</td>
           <td align="right" headers="Y10 i0">1,760</td>
        </tr> ...
```

It defines a header tr, Y0, Y1 ... Y10 as actual date and next tr refers to it.

your help appreciated!

Comment: `df_list = pd.read_html(ksContent.prettify())` (after importing pandas as pd) will give you a list of 8 dataframes. I didn't see the original table so I'm not sure what it's supposed to look like but you can pick through those e.g. `df_list[0].head()` and see if one or a few of them are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to convert it into a list of dataframes

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/keystatsAjax.html?t=tou&culture=en-CA&region=CAN'
lm_json = requests.get(url).json()
df_list=pd.read_html(lm_json["ksContent"])
```

You can iterate through it and get the dataframes one by one. You can also use [dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to get rid of the NaN only rows.

Sample output screenshot from my jupyter Notebook

[image]