# Converting ordinary data into time seris dataframes panda Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, google-colaboratory

I have a small problem concerning conversion of data to time series. Here are the steps that i carried out.
I have the output data as follows :
Beautiful Soup is a library that makes it easy to scrape information from web pages. It sits atop an HTML or XML parser, providing Pythonic idioms for iterating, searching, and modifying the parse tree.

```
url1 = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=xxx&t=BBRI'
url2 = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getKeyStatPart.html?&callback=xxx&t=BBRI'

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(json.loads(re.findall(r'xxx\((.*)\)', requests.get(url1).text)[0])['componentData'], 'lxml')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(json.loads(re.findall(r'xxx\((.*)\)', requests.get(url2).text)[0])['componentData'], 'lxml')

def print_table(soup):
    for i, tr in enumerate(soup.select('tr')):
        row_data = [td.text for td in tr.select('th, td') if td.text]
        if not row_data:
            continue
        if len(row_data) < 12:
            row_data = ['X'] + row_data
        for j, td in enumerate(row_data):
            if j==0:
                print('{: >30}'.format(td))
            else:
                print('{: ^12}'.format(td))
        print()


print_table(soup1)
```

produce output

```
          X
  2010-12   
  2011-12   
  2012-12   
  2013-12   
  2014-12   
  2015-12   
  2016-12   
  2017-12   
  2018-12   
  2019-12   
    TTM     

               Revenue IDR Mil
 30,552,600 
 40,203,051 
 43,104,711 
 51,133,344 
 59,556,636 
 69,813,152 
 82,504,537 
 90,844,308 
 99,067,098 
108,468,320 
105,847,159
```

I need to convert it to a dataframe with panda being to:

```
data

   X        Revenue IDR Mil
  2010-12        30,552,600 
  2011-12        40,203,051 
  2012-12        43,104,711
  2013-12        51,133,344    
  2014-12        59,556,636    
  2015-12        69,813,152  
  2016-12        82,504,537   
  2017-12        90,844,308 
  2018-12        99,067,098   
  2019-12        108,468,320   
  2020-12        105,847,159
```

Comment: `df.reset_index()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit simplified from what you are doing, but I think it gets you where you need, mostly from [Bitto Bennichan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261024/morningstar-keystat-to-pandas-dataframe),

```
import json
import pandas as pd

url1 = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?t=BBRI'
url2 = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getKeyStatPart.html?t=BBRI'

lm_json = requests.get(url1).json()
df_list=pd.read_html(lm_json["componentData"])
df_list[0].transpose()
```